# Default value in Autocomplete in material ui v4

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using Material UI v4.

I have a component which takes all the users and show them in dropdown but I am not able to select default value. I tried following sandbox but it did not worked for me: [https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4mhcj?file=/demo.js][CodeSandBox]

For ex- **test@gmail.com**

react-hook-form : ^7.20.5

I tried giving a default value to both Controller and Autocomplete but it does not work for the first time.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
// data is something like 
// [{name: 'ABCDE', email: 'ABCDEEE@gmail.com'}, {name: 'eeeeee', email: 'eeeeee12@gmail.com'}]

const UserSelection = ({ data = [], onChangeHandler }) => {
  const { control } = useForm({});
  const selectedUserEmail = "ABCDEEE@gmail.com";

  return (
    <>
        <Controller
          name="combo-box-demo"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={data.find(item => item.email === selectedUserEmail)}
          render={()  =>
            <Autocomplete
              id="combo-box-demo"
              size="small"
              options={data}
              defaultValue={data.find(item => item.email === selectedUserEmail)}
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
              getOptionLabel={option => option.name }
              renderOption={option => option.name}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="outlined"
                  placeholder="Select"
                />
              )}
            />
          }
        />
    </>
  );
};

export default UserSelection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, so I am posting here:

The problem was data which was coming is asynchronous and autocomplete was not able to render it properly.

For now I am using:

```
const UserSelection = ({ data = [], onChangeHandler }) => {
  const selectedUser = {name: 'ABCDE', email: 'ABCDEEE@gmail.com'};

  return (
    <Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={data}
    defaultValue={selectedUser}
    onInputChange={onChangeHandler}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.name }
    renderOption={option => option.name}
    renderInput={(params) => (
       <TextField
        {...params}
         variant="outlined"
         placeholder="Select"
       />
    )}
  />
  );
};
export default UserSelection;
```

And where ever I am using above component, I use like

```
data ? <UserSelection/> : null
```

Also instead of using **onChange** I used **onInputChange** which helps in getting default value

then it works and loads default user, hope it helps to community